# FMDatabase: perform the operation: Insert, Update, Select, Delete

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

I am developing iPhone application using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). I decided to use [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Using fmdb, how do I perform the following operation:-Insert, Update, Select, Delete?

As I can't develop application using FMDatabase. I downloaded FMDatabase files which contain following files namely =>

1. FMDatabase.h
2. FMDatabase.m
3. FMResultSet.h
4. FMResultSet.m
5. FMDatabaseAdditions.h
6. FMDatabaseAdditions.m
7. fmdb.m

But the file `fmdb.m` also contains the `main` function. So it is conflicting with my applications MAIN function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fmdb.m is a file that contains FMDB sample code. You should not include this file in your Xcode project. But you should review it to see how to work with FMDB. It contains a lot of well-commented examples.

Answer (score 3):

to use `fmdb` in your code, just add the files you list to your project, except the `main.m` file. Here is an example of using it, when the app finish launching, a SQLite database will be created.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 


    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmp.db"];
    if (![db open]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not open db.");

    }

    [db executeUpdate:@"create table test (a text, b text, c integer, d double, e double)"];

    NSLog(@"%@",[db databasePath]);
    [db beginTransaction];
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < 20) {
        [db executeUpdate:@"insert into test (a, b, c, d, e) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ,
         @"hi'", // look!  I put in a ', and I'm not escaping it!
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number %d", i],
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:i],
         [NSDate date],
         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.2f]];
    }
    [db commit];

    [db close];


}
```

Notice, I'm just pasting some code from fmdb `main.m` file, into `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: Thanks Cesar. Are you talking about "main.m" of MY PROJECT? If yes, is the program going to run without main function?

Comment: I mean the `main.m` of `fmdb`, enjoy.

Comment: - Thanks for reply. My application is completed but still its NOT WORKING. There are no errors or warning. What to do? Can you check my code ? Here is the link for code         http://hotfile.com/dl/107779113/562bfde/InsertDataSample.zip.html

Comment: it would be easier to post your code to github and ask for reviews, rather than posting a zip file.